# Service location for convenience

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, service-locator

I have 2 questions regarding the following code snippet:

```
public class Provider
{
    private static Provider _instance;

    /* Internals ommited. */

    public static Provider Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Provider()); }
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly Provider _dependency;

    public Consumer()
        : this(Provider.Instance)
    {
    }

    public Consumer(Provider dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    /* Internals ommited. */
}
```

1) The second constructor uses the dependency injection pattern, what is the first one doing? Service location?

2) Is it common practice to provide such an overloaded ctor which uses a default instance? Or are there better ways to do something like this? (I would like to avoid implementing a wrapper class).

Comment: It's a singleton. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @kenny, Provider has a reference to a single instance but is not a complete singleton. The Provider should define its default constructor as private, otherwise anyone could create a Provider instance just by saying `new Provider()`. Besides, The default constructor of the Consumer uses the single instance defined in Provider, but it doesn't mean all the Consumer instances will reference that instance. A new Consumer can be created passing a different Provider thanks to the second constructor. In fact, someone could also extend Provider and create Consumers with instances of the child class

Comment: @JonathanMoralesVélez yes, it's a bad singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The first constructor is using static dependency injection. This pattern allows classes derived from `Provider` to be injected for testing purposes, or as an alternative to the default `Provider` implementation at runtime. `Provider` itself may be a service locator - that depends on what objects or services it actually provides.

In this example, though, `Provider` is injected into `Consumer`. That's dependency injection, not service locator (which requires a class to determine it's own dependencies, causing close coupling between them). Thanks to the dependency injection, it doesn't matter to the `Consumer` class if it gets the default implementation of `Provider`, or a class derived from it. The classes could be more loosely coupled if a) `Provider` was an interface, and b) if client code always determined which instance to inject, instead of having a default.

2) Personally, I think static providers are a code smell, but they do work, and may be completely appropriate in your code-base. Ideally, `Provider` should be a singleton factory injected by a dependency injection framework. We have static providers in the code-base I work on at the moment, and I'm slowly replacing them in this way. `Consumer` should have a single constructor - the second one.

Comment: Isn't such a provider facility - like you describe - a service locator? Maybe I have a totally wrong understanding of that Service Locator thing. ;)

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you need some more detail, I'll add some.

Answer (score 1):

> The second constructor uses the dependency injection pattern, what is
>   the first one doing? Service location?

Assuming that `Provider` is the dependency itself and not some kind of registry then no, it's still dependency injection. You are just providing a default value for the dependency for convenience.

> Is it common practice to provide such an overloaded ctor which uses a
>   default instance? Or are there better ways to do something like this?
>   (I would like to avoid implementing a wrapper class).

It's definitely OK, but you might want to consider a factory method as an alternative to a default constructor:

```
public static Consumer CreateDefault()
{
    return new Consumer(Provider.Default);
}
```

This way you avoid the possibility of your clients glossing over the fact that the default constructor makes a (possibly important) choice on their behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the factory method.